# Can't mount ext4 with StickMount

Tags: usb-on-the-go

I have a 2nd generation Nexus 7 running Android 4.4.4. I rooted it, got an OTG cable and tried to mount something using StickMount. It always says it mounts things successfully, but in the case of ext4 partitions, I just find an empty folder at the mount point. Fat32 partitions work fine. What could be the problem and how to check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to mount ext4 with stickmount alone, but I had some success using USB OTG Helper with stickmount still installed. If I use USB OTG Helper to do the mounting, it mounts ext4 successfully (even if it says "no drives mounted"). Both apps need to be installed at the same time for this to work.